# PageControl: keep owner-drawn BG after window overlapping

Tags: delphi

I have owner-drawn TPageControl which draws SpTBX themed BG in OnDrawTab.

[image: owner draw]

Now if i move some window over my app, PageControl doesn't see it and it draws itself with clBtnFace color.

[image: bad draw]

How to achieve correctly painting of BG, even with window overlapping? ie, in what event handler of PageControl do I need to paint BG?
Maybe in some message handler, in overrided TMyPageControl?

Comment: What is the remit of `OnDrawTab`? Sounds like it's job is to draw a single tab. In which case the result you get is to be expected.

Comment: @David, yes, but how to achive correct repainting of PageControl (i may paint BG not in OnDrawTab but in other event handler).

Comment: You need to paint it in response to that part of the window being invalidated. Presumably `OnDrawTab` is only fired when the invalid region of the window includes the tab. I still don't know what control you are using. Is it a vanilla TPageControl? What is SpTBX?

Comment: @David, SpTBX is SpTBXLib (Silverpoint development). I use TTntPageControl with owner-draw, and call SpTBX code to paint an area